# Blazor Cascading Parameter - Using a class to store the values not update the parent reference

Tags: c#, parameters, blazor, parent-child, blazor-webassembly

I'm starting with Blazor, checking a simple example of how to implement Cascading Parameters.

I'm trying to use a class and send it as Cascading parameter, the class has two params and one method to change both values.

If I use it in the parent, everything works fine, but if I tried to call the method to change the values, works in the child component, but not in the parent.

I assume should be related that the parent component needs to call the method `StateHasChanged();` but I cannot access it through the class.

There is the code of the components:

### Parent

```
<div style="border: 5px solid; border-radius: 10px; padding: 10px; margin: 5px">
    <h2>
        Level 1
    </h2>

    <div>
        Counter: <code>@cascadingClass.Counter</code>.
        <input type="button" value="Call method 'AddOne()'" @onclick="cascadingClass.AddOne"/>
    </div>
    <div>
        Message: <code>@cascadingClass.Message</code>.
    </div>
    <div>
        <CascadingValue Value="@cascadingClass" Name="CascadingClassParam">
            <CascadingParametersLevel2/>
        </CascadingValue>
    </div>
</div>

@code
{
    CascadingClass cascadingClass = new CascadingClass();

    public class CascadingClass
    {
        public int Counter { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }

        public CascadingClass()
        {
            Counter = 50;
            Message = "Initialized";
        }

        public void AddOne()
        {
            Counter++;
            Message = "Value changed!";
        }
    }
}
```

### Child

```
@using static blazor_training.Client.Shared.Playground.CascadingParametersLevel1

<div style="border: 3px solid; border-radius: 10px; padding: 10px; margin: 5px">
    <h2>
        Level 2
    </h2>
    <div>
        Counter @cascadingClass.Counter <input type="button" value="+1" @onclick="addOne"/>
    </div>
    <div>
        Message: @cascadingClass.Message
    </div>
</div>

@code {

    [CascadingParameter(Name = "CascadingClassParam")]
    protected CascadingClass cascadingClass { get; set; }

    private void addOne()
    {
        cascadingClass.AddOne();
    }

}
```

### Actual behavior

[image: Blazor example]

So, I'm missing something important about the good practices of the Blazor Cascading Params? Or there is an easier way to achieve this?

## My answer

The question was marked as duplicate, anyway, I left my answer / fix

### Parent

```
<div style="border: 5px solid; border-radius: 10px; padding: 10px; margin: 5px">
    <h2>
        Level 1
    </h2>

    <div>
        Counter: <code>@cascadingClass.Counter</code>.
        <input
            type="button"
            value="Call method 'AddOne()'"
            @onclick="cascadingClass.AddOne"/>
    </div>
    <div>
        Message: <code>@cascadingClass.Message</code>.
    </div>
    <div>
        <CascadingValue Value="@cascadingClass" Name="CascadingClassParam">
            <CascadingParametersLevel2/>
        </CascadingValue>
    </div>
</div>

@code
{
    private CascadingClass cascadingClass;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        cascadingClass = new CascadingClass(this.StateHasChanged);
    }

    public class CascadingClass
    {
        public int Counter { get; private set; }
        public string Message { get; private set; }
        private Action _refreshParent;

        public CascadingClass(Action stateHasChanged)
        {
            Counter = 50;
            Message = "Initialized";
            _refreshParent = stateHasChanged;
        }

        public void AddOne()
        {
            Counter++;
            Message = "Value changed!";
            _refreshParent();
        }
    }
}
```

### Child

```
@using static blazor_training.Client.Shared.Playground.CascadingParametersLevel1

<div style="border: 3px solid; border-radius: 10px; padding: 10px; margin: 5px">
    <h2>
        Level 2
    </h2>
    <div>
        Counter @cascadingClass.Counter
        <input
            type="button"
            value="+1"
            @onclick="addOne"/>
    </div>
    <div>
        Message: @cascadingClass.Message
    </div>
</div>

@code {

    [CascadingParameter(Name = "CascadingClassParam")]
    protected CascadingClass cascadingClass { get; set; }

    private void addOne()
    {
        cascadingClass.AddOne();
    }

}
```

Comment: I was going to post an answer, but can't.  You add an event in the `CascadingClass` and raise it whenever you change anything in the class.  Any component needing to update registers for the event in `OnInitialized` and calls `StateHasChanged`.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the update @MrCakaShaunCurtis - I added my solution into the Question body 